# Change build settings in Xamarin Studio so that missing reference isn't interpreted as error

Tags: build, compiler-errors, xamarin, linker-errors, xamarin-studio

Is it possible to change the build settings in Xamarin Studio 5.5.3 so that some errors are interpreted as warnings? E.g. a missing reference is no build error anymore?

How can I do this?

Comment: A missing reference is definitely a build error no matter what. Your code won't run. Can you give details on the specific error you are seeing?

Comment: I include a dll from another project. I have this dll locally but for Jenkins I inserted a reference to the current project repository (placeholder). This repository isn't available locally. I think the build process with Jenkins has to be reconsidered ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A missing reference is always a build error. In the case of Xamarin, things like linking, AOT, compile to native, etc. can't be performed at all to create an application package.

You should include the missing DLL in your repository, so it is always there.

Or better yet, distribute it via NuGet so you can update it. You can host your own NuGet feed for this purpose or try [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a look into NuGet.